# NumPy Dot Product Matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Is there a NumPy matrix/vector function that does,

```
         [x1*y1]
         [x2*y2]
x*y  =   [x3*y3]
         [-----]
         [xn*yn]
```

Comment: You mean `x * y`?

Comment: You really need to read the docs then. There's no confusion. Matrix multiplication is a different function.

Comment: How did you create `x` and `y`?  With `np.array` or `np.matrix`?  Or just as lists of lists.  That makes a difference in how operators like `*` behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method, **just use ***

For example, consider

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
           [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

b = np.array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
           [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])

print(a * b)
```

This code returns

```
[[ 0  2  4  6  8]
 [10 12 14 16 18]]
```

Comment: Are you saying I could convert my matrices into arrays and than multiply them.

Comment: the array imported from numpy can store matrices as well. Afterall, 2D matrices are 2D arrays.

Comment: Yes. To get them back you can use .tolist()

Comment: better to use `import numpy as np`, and use `np.array(....)`.  There's less confusion, especially in this case where `*` is being used in two very different ways.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use arrays instead of matrices, matrices will go away some day. A matrix multiplication operator, @, can be used with arrays in recent versions of NumPy when you use Python 3.5+. Having a matrix multiplication operator was pretty much the only reason for matrices.